# Arcade expression for multi fields

Tags: arcade, arcgis-enterprise

I am new to Arcade and I am trying to symbolize a feature based on a domain value in multiple fields.

The feature class is named Zones and there are 3 fields Phase1, Phase2, Phase3 with the same Domain assigned to each field. The Domain values are [Active, Complete, Future]

I want to create an expression when Phase1, Phase2 or Phase 3 = Active

I am using a hosted feature class on Enterprise 10.6.1

Comment: Which product from the ArcGIS platform are you using Arcade with here?

Comment: I am using a hosted feature class on Enterprise 10.6.1

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer below.

//This Arcade expression is used to show only the features that contains a Domain value of "Active" when there are multiple fields that contain the same Domain.

var StatusArray = [DomainName($feature,"phase1"), DomainName($feature,"phase2"), DomainName($feature,"phase3")]

Boolean(IndexOf (StatusArray, 'Active') >= 0)